# Increasing the size if UIButton by pinching in iphone

Tags: iphone, uibutton, touch

I have a UIButton & want to increase the size of UIButton by pinching the UIButton.Is it possible with UIButton similarly to UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Just get the gesture and then scale your button accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, I was about to say no, but this probably would work.  I can't see this looking good but that's another matter.

Comment: Yes, it's not an easy task, but if you can get the gesture then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://rogchap.com/2011/06/10/ios-image-manipulation-with-uigesturerecognizer-scale-move-rotate/) you have nice tutorial with gesture recognizers. For pinching use `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` after hooking it up you can retrieve scale of pinching easily. In your case don't use affine transform to scale, because it will cause blurring of the button. Instead, you should calculate frame of button by hand. This is more complicated, but result should be exactly what you want.